# How to get all security groups in aws using ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, aws-security-group

I have an ansible playbook that is supposed to get all the security groups that are in a region.
It has mfa authentication also.

```
- name: Generate temporary access keys and token
  sts_assume_role:
    duration_seconds: 900
    region: "{{ region }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{user_access_key}}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{user_secret_key}}"
    mfa_serial_number: "{{user_mfa_serial}}"
    role_arn: "{{role_arn}}"
    mfa_token: "{{mfa_token}}"
    role_session_name: "{{role_session_name}}"
  register: assumed_role
  
- name: ec2 security group information fetch
  ec2_group_facts:
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
    filters:{}
  register: result

- debug: msg="{{ result.security_groups }}"
```

The problem is, when I run it when I run it, I only get the default SG only. But I want all the security groups.
When I add filter to a particular vpc-id it results to empty yet that vpc exists.

What could be the issue??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to include `region` in `ec2_group_info` it now looks like this.

```
- name: ec2 security group information fetch
  ec2_group_info:
    region: "{{region}}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
  register: result
```